# How to make a clone of DateTime object

Tags: perl, datetime

I have some code as follow:

```
        my $d1 = $start_date;
        $c->log->debug(Dumper($start_date));

        my @date_range;

        while($d1 <= $end_date){
            push @date_range, $d1->day();
            $d1->add(days => 1);
        }
```

How can I do to prevent $start_date changed?

Comment: Finally, $start_date = $end_date + 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use clone method:

```
my $date = new DateTime();
my $temp_date = $date->clone();
```

It will be a copy and not a reference. If instead you do the below:

```
my $temp_date = $date;
```

then both will refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

In perl, objects are scalar references. When you do "my $d1 = $start_date" you are making $d1 a referemce which refers to the same object as $start_date.

You probably want to modify a copy of $start_date. I don't know what class $start_date is, but see if that class provides a copy constructor for you to use.

Comment: Exactly that I want, I use my $d1 = $start_date->clone();

Comment: The questioner changed his title to mention that after I replied. :)